# Where is Telegram for Android developed? (Or: is it really free software?)

Tags: open-source, telegram

[Telegram](https://telegram.org/) is supposed to be [free/libre software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), but where is Telegram for Android developed?

1. Copy of the code: I can't find recent code. https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram claims to be the official repository but was last updated 2 months ago at 3.10.1, while 3.11.2 is currently being distributed. **Is there a way to get the actual code in use?**
2. Patching the code: as far as I can see, [pull requests](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/pulls) are never merged, even when they aren't explicitly rejected. (Perhaps some of them get merged in another repository and the recent code is sometimes published to this repository?) **How to send a patch?**
3. According to https://core.telegram.org/tsi/bugs, Telegram uses Trello as issue tracker, but no link is provided and [auchry says](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/1137#issuecomment-143573800) the issue tracker was just between [2014](https://web.archive.org/web/20141009152955/https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/issues) and 2015. **How to send bug reports?** Should one use https://telegram.org/support?

In short: is Telegram really free software? Is it even open source?

Comment: I see there is a fork for f-droid: https://github.com/slp/Telegram-FOSS

Comment: There's an interesting entry on their FAQ: [Why not open source everything?](https://telegram.org/faq#q-why-not-open-source-everything), although I also have a doubt if this answers any of your question...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's on the private repo of Owner, and sync time to time with the public repo on the github repo.

[DrKLO](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/pull/76#issuecomment-34425677):

> I have my own private repo except this on github, where i pushing all
>   changes with unfinished things, because i can work from not only one
>   place. After all new features are tested, I pushing new code to
>   github, So github contains only major updates that will go to google
>   play, so i think there is no need for tags, because every commit is
>   release version. If i remove something from this repo, for me it will
>   be harder to merge all new changes from my private repo.
>
> I will think about this pull request later, when I finish all
>   important features.

Answer (score 0):

The App is free and will always be.

> Telegram is free and will stay free — no ads, no subscription fees, forever.
>   - [Telegram FAQ](https://telegram.org/faq#q-how-is-telegram-different-from-whatsapp)

Apparently they are not updating the code right after each release, but after a month or two they do (Usually.)

To submit a bug you can Contact Telegram Support within the app, Settings >> Ask A Question.

In short: It is a free software, And its somewhat open source...